# Encoding - what is it and why do we need it?

Tags: encoding

Can someone explaing me about encoding and its importance. I understand that we have various encodings and in each of them first 127 characters are same.

Comment: Please read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and you shall be enlightened.

Comment: @Charles: +1 for barely beating me to it, and for the "you shall be enlightened" formulation.

Answer (score 5):

Read [Joel Spolsky's excellent article on the subject](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

An interesting point that was noted in the discussion of another answer (which I didn't really think the author needed to delete) is that there is a difference between a *character set*, which (in the other author's words - don't remember his username) defines a mapping between integers and characters (e.g. "Capital A is 65"), and an *encoding*, which defines how those integers are to be represented in a byte stream. Most old character sets, such as ASCII, have only one very simple encoding: each integer becomes exactly one byte. The Unicode character set, on the other hand, has many different encodings, none of which are equally simple: UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32...

Comment: Looks like an extra closing bracket slipped in there.

Comment: DEC’s [Radix-50](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Radix-50) is an old character set even smaller than ASCII with only 40 characters total, that comes in two distinct encoding schemes: one for 16-bit systems and the other for 36-bit systems.

Comment: @tchrist: Interesting; I didn't know about that one - also very interesting that it put several characters into one byte. By the way, I corrected "Most old encodings" to "Most old character sets". Fortunately, the word "Most" was there all the time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) above mentioned by Aasmund Eldhuset, I find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRdupNXpm8k) Tedx Talk really interesting and explanatory on the same topic.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I think encoding is the technique to convert your message into a form that is not readable to unauthorized persons so that you can maintain your secrecy.

Comment: Your answer needs to be more clear and supported by an example or reference.